How to wrap ng-select in custom form controller?
I've tried to create a stackblitz to show what I'm talking about, but I cannot get it to work at all so I'm resorting to just asking for help.  I have 2 components:
Component 1 is a custom form controller that wraps an ng-select and adds custom search functionality against a backend:
<div>
  <label>Custom Component</label>
  <ng-select
    [items]="items | async"
    .. Other properties
  ><ng-select>
  <span *ngIf="select.value < 3">Type 3 characters to search</span>
</div>

Component 2 is a form that I'd like to use the customer controller in:
<form formGroup="fg">
  <custom-controller
    formControllerName="custom-prop"
  >
  </custom-controller>
</form>

In my custom controller I've implemented the ControlValueAccessor and I'm able to manually read the value from the ng-input and push it to the form.  What I'm struggling with is the reverse (i.e. formGroup changes and I'd like the ng-select to reflect that).  I've come up with a few ways of doing it, but they all seem really complicated and flaky.
Is there not a simple way to pass the formControllerName to the ng-select in my custom-controller and it function as expected?
Any examples of this working would be hugely appreciated as I'm struggling to find anything.

I suppose you have mistyped "formControllerName", should be formControlName.
Idea of such decorator component that you've created is to have something like "model" property that you use in <ng-select [ngModel]="model" ...>.
In ControlValueAccessor you had to implement writeValue which is the callback method that will be triggered once control value is changed from outside.
So doing
writeValue(val: ...): void {
  this.model = val;
  // might need cd.markForCheck() depending on your cd strategy
}

should do the trick for you.
One more thing that you can face is that you if your BE data is paginated then when you populate control from outside with value that stands on page 2 of your BE response but you load page 1 initially then there will be missing item to match the model, so there will need some additional handling for such cases. But this one is a bit another thing that might not be needed for you since idk your details

If your control extends from ControlValueAccessor you need define a function
onChange:any;

And
 registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
 }

Each time you change the value in your component you call to the function onChange:
 this.onChange(what---ever---)

And the function write value it's to give value to the variables of your component, received the value of the FormControl or the [ngModel]
  writeValue(value: any[]|any): void {
    this.value=value; //<--or whatever
  }

